#  why eclipse can not detect android device?

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse can't detect my android device but it can run with the emulator. i have no problem with the android device setting since it work well in my old laptop.

any idea?

Comment: what do you mean by old laptop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you start the Device sometimes adb doesn't recognize it because it has already started. So, in that case you just need to reset adb from `DDMS->Devices`

[image]

Comment: I know for my Acer A200, even though it installs drivers, you need to install the drivers from the website.  Make sure that all your drivers are also up to date.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `android-sdk/platform-tools/` via command promt...

write command.. `adb devices` (It will show the list of attached devices)

If its not display device number then look at the drivers of device on your system. And if display then just restart eclipse..

Answer (score 2):

Check that the android:minSdkVersion is lower or equal to the Version running on the phone. If it is higher it wont show on "Android Device Chooser"

Answer (score 1):

Also, after installing the usb drivers you may need to set your Android device to developer mode and enable USB debugging on your device before it will be seen by adb or eclipse.  From http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

2.Enable USB debugging on your device. ◦On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings > Applications > Development.

On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer options.

Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i ran adb-devices and it did show my device and it was unauthorized on the PC I was using.
I went to developer tools and disabled and then enabled USB debugging. It then prompted me for authorization for that computer, and then it worked fine.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This helped me.  I had to revoke all USB permissions, then toggled USB debugging, re-accept my computer and my device appeared in Eclipse a second later..

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting using the command prompt ./adb connect 192.168.xxx.xxx:5555

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Linux you will have to add your device to the /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules file.

Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html . Its a document on using hardware devices.

Answer (score 0):

haven't you enable 'debug mode' in your Android device?
If not, then please enable it first. Then follow the steps in this article. 
This example use Lenovo P770 as a device.
http://www.mywordismyopinion.com/2014/02/experience-using-smartphone-lenovo-p770.html

-hope this is helpful, :).

Answer (score -2):

just install any driver are any compatibility software provided by your device provider like Samsung provide kies,Htc provide Sync etc..

Either check check your sysytem or antivirus not block it.